# How to convert SVG string to file or PNG in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, svg, imagemagick, png

I'm sending a SVG string from browser (Javascript) to a server that is running Rails (Ruby). I want to convert this string to a PNG with transparency or, at least, a SVG file so I can convert it later

Any ideas? I installed RMagick but I'm still not sure how to create the file from the string.

Any other solution to achieve this?

The idea is to create simple "logos" dynamically

Answer (score 12):

With RMagick, just read the string into an image instance with [Image.from_blob](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#from_blob) + [defining the SVG format](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/info.html#format)

```rb
require "RMagick"

svg_string='
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="120" height="120" viewPort="0 0 120 120" version="1.1">
  <rect width="150" height="150" fill="rgb(0, 255, 0)" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" />
  <line x1="20" y1="100" x2="100" y2="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>'

img = Magick::Image.from_blob(svg_string) {
  self.format = 'SVG'
  self.background_color = 'transparent'
}
img.write "example_out.png"
```

[image: How to convert SVG string to file or PNG in Ruby]

**Edit**

If the string is just a SVG path, there's `Magick::Draw.path` to "rebuild" vector graphics. Doc & examples [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/draw.html#path).

Comment: NOTE: on rmagick (3.2.0) I had to change the last line to `img[0].write()`

Answer (score 0):

We did this with some SVG charts we generated with c3/d3.  We ended up using Capybara to visit a web page that rendered the SVG, and then saving a snapshot of the page.

Comment: can you share more details?